# Dojo Query need help in selecting the elements in a page

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have HTML page with following elements

```
<img src='some link' id='_id_portlet1_1234' > link </img>     
<img src='some link' id='_id_portlet2_4567' > link </img>
```

I has to select all the id elements with a pattern of `_id_portlet*` with dojo.query. Can you guys help in providing the  dojo.query to get list of above id elements. Here the source code is generated by a template file and every time the page is rendered a random number will be appended to the id. I need to select all the elements which are following the pattern of `_id_portlet*`. Thanks for your help

Comment: <img src='some link' id='_id_portlet1_1234' > link </img>
<img src='some link' id='_id_portlet2_4567' > link </img>

Comment: In the above description actual HTML elements are truncated. Please refer to above HTML tags

Comment: The `id` must begin with a letter (A-Z or a-z), and can be followed by letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_"). Your IDs aren't valid

Comment: I see elements that start with _(underscore) in all my pages and they work as expected. Refer to www.t-mobile.com site and check the "view source". You will find HTML elements with id that start with "_".

Comment: @ravikuni Maybe it works because your browser isn't compliant, but that's not valid, so you shouldn't use that. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing - the `<img>` has no closing tag, so instead of invalid

```
<img src="some link" id="_portlet1_1234" class="portlet"> link </img>
```

you should use

```
<img src="some link" id="_portlet1_1234" class="portlet" />
```

---

And for selecting the images try this

```
dojo.query('img[id^="_id_portlet"]').style("border", "5px solid red");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uWGeT/)

Comment: `<img>` has closing tag in HTML5 (if I remember it well)

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @Oriol - nope :) there is no closing tag for `<img>` even in HTML5

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. Your solution is working like charm. Thanks alot.

Comment: @ravikuwi I though `<img>` has closing tag in HTML5, but it was XHTML2 instead: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-image.html#sec_20.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes:

```
<img src="some link" id="portlet1_1234" class="portlet"> link </img>     
<img src="some link" id="portlet2_4567" class="portlet"> link </img>
```

And then I don't know dojo, but in normal javascript you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("portlet");
```

Adding `_id_` at the beggining of the `id` it's a pleonasm.

Comment: I see elements that start with (underscore) in all my pages and they work as expected. Refer to www.t-mobile.com site and check the "view source". You will find HTML elements with id that start with "_".

Comment: Also I don't have control over generated source code and it generates the elements with id stat with "_". Ignore the id's that start with "_". Let say I have id's with below pattern "portlet1_1234" and "portlet_2345". Can you help in providing the either Java script code or dojo to select these elements.

Comment: @Oriol - in HTML5 the `id` attribute can start with **any** character, underscore is totally valid